# How to add space between CSS table rows?

Tags: html, css

I have a grid that is using CSS `display: table;`.

What I would like to do is to have a gap between the rows.

Is there a way I can do that when using `display: table-row;`. I already tried `padding` and `margin` but these don't work for me as I want to set the margin background color.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your grid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### For Individual Cells

You can achieve this with a transparent `border`:

```
border: 5px solid transparent;
```

---

To do this for just the top and bottom of the cells, you can use:

```
border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
border-top: 5px solid transparent;
```

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### For Every Cell

If you want to add this to *every* cell in your table, you can use the `border-spacing` CSS property on the element set to `display: table`:

```
border-spacing: 5px;
```

```css
.table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
  display: table;
}

.table-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
  background: #5ae;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 1 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 Cell 1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">Row 2 Cell 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a colored background so it makes it easier to visualize.

Comment: @SamanthaJ I've added the background on the *For Every Cell* example. As the border is transparent, the *For Individual Cells* example will inherit the background of the cell itself, so unless you were to specify a non-transparent border colour it would make the entire surrounding area a solid colour.

Comment: Your solution looks good but what I was really wanting was spacing between rows only and not rows and columns.  Do you have any idea if this is possible.  Thanks.

Comment: @SamanthaJ in that case you need only specify `border-top` and/or `border-bottom`. The `border` property targets all four sides.

Comment: Thanks. Can you update your example and add in some background color to the table, cells and rows if that would help to make more clear. Glad to hear there's a solution

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
border-spacing:5px;
border-collapse: separate;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

```css
.table{  
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px 10px;
    display:table;
}

.table .row {
  display: table-row;
}

.table .cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
    <div class="cell">x</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">x</div>
    <div class="cell">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works for both vertical and horizontal but I just want rows spaced

Comment: `border-spacing: 10px 10px;` has two properites first one is for horizontal and second is for vertical if you want horizontal only then write `border-spacing: 10px 0;`

Answer (score -4):

All you have to do is add a margin to your rows in CSS.

```
tr{
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```